# Passing Label by reference

Tags: c#

I have a little simple method where I would like to pass in a label.

Now by my reading, anything based off the object class should automatically pass by reference, so this was my first try at my method:

```
        public static void ValiateStepAsInt(String Step, int? Value, Label Error)
        {
            if (Value == null && Step != "")
            {
                Error.Text = "Error!!!";
                return;
            }
            Error.Text = "";
        }
```

I didn't get any compilor errors, but whenever i called this, it would set the Error.text, but once it got out of the method, that value would disappear (so not really pass by reference).

So next I added the "ref" option to the Label Error; hoping this might fix the issue, but still the same thing, the method sets it, but once its done, ths value disappears.

What I am missing when trying to pass a label by reference?

Comment: Aside from the *actual* reason you're losing the error, your understanding of "pass by reference" is flawed. Please read http://pobox.com/~skeet/csharp/parameters.html

Comment: @JonSkeet:  thanks for the good reading material

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're resetting the `Text` property to an empty string just below your conditional statement. Maybe you want to wrap `Error.Text = "";` into an `else`.

If that's not it, then perhaps you're setting the value somewhere else as well and thus overwrite the change in the method you've shown us here.

Comment: Oh man!  My original method that was a return!  I forgot to add the else logic!  D'oh!

Answer (score 3):

Isn't the value disappearing because of this line of code:

```
Error.Text = "";
```

You are setting the Label to an empty string just before the method returns.

Maybe you means to do this:

```
public static void ValiateStepAsInt(String Step, int? Value, Label Error)
{
    if (Value == null && Step != "")
    {
        Error.Text = "Error!!!";
    }
    else
    {
        Error.Text = "";
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah, i screwed up.  in my original function that was a return, I forgot to add in the else statement!